How can I implement a feature to export and import database to my app in android(Kotlin)
How can I add feature to export and import database to my app. currently I am learning the data persistence using room. I have created a database and I want that my user should be able to export and import database. Lets say my user wants to share the database to a another user. How can I implement a feature so that my user can simply export the database and share it using any app like WhatsApp , email or something like that and then other user should just be able to import it to his app.
I am  beginner I don't have any experience on android development , so please consider giving answer in a scope which I can understand. Your help is much appreciated.

For what it is worth, I cover Room import/export in this chapter of this free book.

There's no easy way to share data like that, especially when you want to be able to share the data as text or link via whatsapp. Assuming you can't encode it into a datastring you would need to export the data to some cloud server storage thing and share a link to that, then import from there. Not a beginner friendly task, can involve cost because you need to store or transfer data. You can maybe build a basic export / import feature and let users share their exported files in whatever ways they chose.

Another option, though probably also quite complex to properly implement, would be to use another database like Couchbase Lite that supports P2P synchronization.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
